# Trying to change two elements on one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to mess around with inputs and I want to give the `input` and the `submit button` *(not an input type, a normal button)* to get box shadows, but only the `input` gets the box-shadow while the `button` only transforms.

Is there a way to do this with javascript, css, or both?

**Here is my CSS:**

```
.submit { 
    transform: translateX(310px) translateY(38px);
    font-size: 38px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.input {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid;
    font-size: 30px;
    transform: translateX(350px) translateY(38px);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.input:focus, .input:focus + .submit {
    outline: none;
    border-top: solid;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-left: solid;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

.input:focus {
    width: 600px;
}

.submit:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, can you get a similar effect with the CSS rule `box-shadow` and avoid the problem?

Comment: i had box-shadow on .input:focus but i deleted while i was struggling to find out a solution.

Comment: You should give a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can reproduce your example easily and help you. Please, post your HTML code as well.

Comment: Check if your button uses .input class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick snippet showing how to get box-shadow on both elements when focused on the input. You could modify depending on your styling. The `input:focus, input:focus + button` selector is the part in which it chooses both elements.

```css
input:focus, input:focus + button {
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `box-shadow` property back onto your button's CSS if you want it to have a box shadow. This codepen I found has a great example of a button with `box-shadow` as well as the `transition` that you already have:

https://codepen.io/LeoPragi/pen/gzrGoG

These are the important parts for your button's CSS:

```
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
```

You are also probably going to want to put the box-shadow on the button's hover instead of on the focus, like in the codepen:

```
.button:hover {
  background-color: #2EE59D;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px rgba(46, 229, 157, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-7px);
}
```